# Separate IP for separate browsers

Tags: browser, ip

Is it possible to use 2 different IP in 2 browsers? I would like to surf in Chrome with IP address A and in IE with IP address B.

If this is possible: how?

Comment: Do you have two different IP addresses?  Usually, every (home) user has only one external IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proxy setting in one of these browsers. [Chrome proxy settings](http://www.googlechrometutorial.com/google-chrome-advanced-settings/Google-chrome-proxy-settings.html)